# rosbuild and roslib are non existent packages and rosdep cant find (missing resource)

Tags: ros, rosdep, roslib, add-dependencies, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to linux and ROS. if i've left out any key info needed to fix the issue, please let me know

I'm using debian 11 (Bullseye). I installed ROS through the following package deb file : https://debian.pkgs.org/11/debian-main-amd64/ros-desktop_1.16_all.deb.html

So far everything works well. I've setup a catkin workspace and have made and built a package. However the dependancies for some source files cant be found: 'rosbuild and 'roslib'.

```
invictus@INVICHOST:~$ rospack depends beginner_tutorials 

[rospack] Error: package 'rosconsole' depends on non-existent package 'rosbuild' and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update'
[rospack] Error: package 'rospy' depends on non-existent package 'roslib' and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update'
cpp_common
rostime
roscpp_traits
roscpp_serialization
catkin
genmsg
genpy
message_runtime
rosconsole
std_msgs
rosgraph_msgs
xmlrpcpp
roscpp
rosgraph
rospy
```

Trying to install via rosdep gives:

```
invictus@INVICHOST:~$ rosdep install roslib

ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource roslib
ROS path [0]=/home/invictus/catkinws/src
ROS path [1]=/usr/share

invictus@INVICHOST:~$ rosdep install rosbuild

ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource rosbuild
ROS path [0]=/home/invictus/catkinws/src
ROS path [1]=/usr/share
```

and doing rosdep update gives:

```
invictus@INVICHOST:~$ rosdep update
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
Hit https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/releases/fuerte.yaml
Query rosdistro index https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index-v4.yaml
Skip end-of-life distro "ardent"
Skip end-of-life distro "bouncy"
Skip end-of-life distro "crystal"
Skip end-of-life distro "dashing"
Skip end-of-life distro "eloquent"
Add distro "foxy"
Add distro "galactic"
Skip end-of-life distro "groovy"
Skip end-of-life distro "hydro"
Skip end-of-life distro "indigo"
Skip end-of-life distro "jade"
Skip end-of-life distro "kinetic"
Skip end-of-life distro "lunar"
Add distro "melodic"
Add distro "noetic"
Add distro "rolling"
updated cache in /home/invictus/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache
```

ROS Package path:

```
invictus@INVICHOST:~$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH 
/home/invictus/catkinws/src
```

What can i do to get these packages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391344/rosbuild-and-roslib-are-non-existent-packages-and-rosdep-cant-find-(missing-resource)/) by [sp1derm4n](https://answers.ros.org/users/90033/sp1derm4n/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you were using released distro I would say use `rosdep install beginner_tutorials` with the package on your path. However you're using what we call the [Upstream Packages](https://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages) which follow slightly different conventions than standard ROS packages.

rosdep was designed to install the dependencies of a source checkout on your path. It itself is not designed to "install" a specific package.

For the upstream packages I did an `apt-cache search roslib` and `apt-cache search rosbuild` and found you can also likely just install the package `sudo apt-get install python3-roslib rosbuild`

However I would strongly recommend that for the best user experience you consider learning to use ROS on one of our officially supported platforms.  [ROS 1 Supported Platforms](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) and [ROS 2 supported platforms](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2021-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1